# How to configure webpack to use compass in my project

Tags: css, webpack, compass

I'm new in webpack and i don't know how we can use Compass ( CSS Authoring Framework ) in a project.

Is there a good method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins)

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "style!css!sass?includePaths[]=" + path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

here is a [helpful webpack boilerplate](https://github.com/AymanJitan/webpackular)

## Update:


You can use [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) that will @import your SASS resources into every required SASS module. where you will never have to import your resources in all your sass files.

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      ...,
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css',
          'sass?outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/compass-mixins/lib'),
          'sass-resources'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  sassResources: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/app/resources/stylesheets/base.scss')
```

please check the implementation [in action in this boilerplate](https://github.com/AymanJitan/webpackular/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L29)

Comment: Nope. That plugin doesn't have `background` mixin. `Module build failed: No mixin named background`

Comment: @Green adding @ import "compass"; to the beginning of every file where I use compass mixins solves this, I am not sure if it's the best approach though

Comment: *@import       ..damn stack overflow exaggerated rules, they wouldn't let me use @ followed by something twice

Comment: @Green all background mixins do exist in the compass-mixins.

Comment: @coiso importing resources (such as compass) in the header of each of your scss files does not make any sense and it seems very redundant. I updated my answer with a solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Essential addition to @Ayman Jitan answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34967698/1114926.

You have to add these two lines at top of your `styles.scss` file:

```
@import "compass";  // <--
@import "compass/functions";  // <--

.foo {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Otherwise you'll get errors from `sass-loader` "Module build failed" and "No mixin" found. Like the following"

```
Module build failed:
undefined
                ^
      No mixin named background
```

If you add only `@import "compass/functions";` (without `@import "compass";`), you may get this error (depends on the mixin you include, in my case it was thrown by `@include background(linear-gradient(white, #cccccc, #aaaaaa));`):

```
Module build failed:
undefined
                          ^
      Media query expression must begin with '('
```

Answer (score 1):

Since compass is a half-ruby and a half-sass framework, [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) may work incorrectly whith legacy scss code.

To enable the original compass in your webpack config, you should use:

[ruby-sass-loader](https://github.com/ddelbondio/ruby-sass-loader)

with the `compass` option.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...    
  module: {
    loaders: [
      /* some other loaders */
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!ruby-sass?compass=1'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

> **NB!**: Compass is [no longer supported](https://github.com/Compass/compass/commit/dd74a1cfef478a896d03152b2c2a3b93839d168e)